# Hesitate to remove utility in my laravel 5.5 project

Tags: laravel-5

How about, some time ago I had installed this utility to monitor the query results in my application, now I want to remove it, but I do not know how, someone knows how I can deactivate it?

[image]

Comment: You mention "removing" and "deactivating", do you want remove the package from your project completely or just disable it? If you only want to disable it you can add `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` in your `.env` file.

Comment: In my case I have this option APP_DEBUG=true, I can not find that variable in my .env, Will that be?

Comment: You have to manually add `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` to your .env file it is not there by default. `APP_DEBUG` determines if your application is is in debug mode or not, which is a feature from [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#configuration) and not from the debugbar package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

That bar at the bottom is called the Laravel Debugbar which is found here: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

It is controlled by a setting in your `.env` file in the root of your project called `APP_DEBUG`. Set this to `false` to hide the bar (recommended for production).

To uninstall it from your project completely, run `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`. Depending on your Laravel version, you may also have to remove the Service Provider from `config/app.php` (under `providers`) or remove it from `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` depending how you originally installed it.

---

Note: If you're caching your config (by using `php artisan config:cache`) then don't forget to clear your config cache after changes by running `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Good. maybe I want to keep it and just turn it off, I have put the following change in .env APP_DEBUG = false, but I still see the bar of records, will I be missing something?

Comment: You were right jamesking56, just missing php artisan cache: clear and php artisan config: cache